# How can I fix this problem with routas de laravel in centos7

Tags: laravel, routes, centos7

I'm working on an old server with apache in centos 7, the problem I have is that I'm setting up a laravel project and I'm having problems routing the put method of a resource so that this resource is modified and in other routes this also happens

```
Example: 
<form action="/model/{{model->id}}/" .... method="POST" >
  @csrf
  @method('PUT')
<form>
or a simple:
<a href="/model" .... >
```

and this happens when I click on **"Base de datos"**

[image: Valid XHTML].

[image: Valid XHTML].

this only happens when I transfer the project to centos 7

Comment: It looks like the mod rewrite module is missing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at Blade syntax, in [Laravel Official docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/blade):

```
<form action="{{ url('model/'.$model->id) }}" method="POST" >
  @csrf
  @method('PUT')
<form>
```